# Virtuemart JavaScript span id (cart subtotal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, virtuemart

Is there a way that I can, in the cart, insert the cart subtotal into Google tracking code conversion value field?

How can I use jQuery to evaluate

```
<span id="tt_order_subtotal"><!--prints as £114.00 for example-->
```

from the virtuemart cart into a variable and thence to an integer.?
I would be very grateful for just even a rough pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var int_val = $('#tt_order_subtotal').text().match(/\d+/)[0];
```